# Is there an omission after 'or similar'?

Tags: grammar

> First-year students will require: 
>       1. Three sets of plain work robes (black)
>  
>       2. One plain pointed hat (black) for day wear 
>       3. One pair of protective gloves (dragon hide ***or similar***) 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is ‘or similar’ an idiom or is there an omission like ‘one’ after similar?

Comment: I think the `one` part is implicit in spoken English.

Comment: I'd say the implied word is `material`, not `one`, but you have the right idea. You see this construct a lot where brevity is valued, such as in directions or lists. As one [blogger](http://www.melskitchencafe.com/2012/07/mels-kitchen-tip-how-i-organize-my-recipes-and-my-favorite-cookbooks-blogs.html) wrote: _the recipes are already in a convenient Word (or similar) document._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A more complete phrase would be something like:

> One pair of protective gloves (**made from** dragon hide or **something** similar **to dragon hide**).

The **omitted** words are implied, as it presents a cleaner, less repetitive structure.

Comment: Yes. It's worth noting that exactly the same deletion is often made with *dragon hide or [something] **equivalent** [to dragon hide]*.